# Remove controller from friendly URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written freindly URLs for the show action of the School Resource but now have

before i had ;

```
http://webaddress/schools/2
```

and now i have;

```
http://webaddress/schools/school_name
```

However, i want

```
http://webaddress/school_name
```

My config routes look like this for the resource;

```
resources :schools do
  collection do
    match 'search' => 'schools#search', via: [:get, :post], as: :search
  end
```

end

How can i achieve that? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more conventional way would be to use the `path:` option in your `route resources`, like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
...
resources :schools, path: "", only: :show #-> has to go at end of file!
```

This will give you the ability to add different methods to this, as well as keeping with Rails conventions :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this at the last your routes file:

```
match ':id' => 'schools#show', via: [:get]
```